# Why is my footer being pushed up when viewed on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have a footer that is responsive up until I view on mobile. When viewed on mobile, the footer is pushed up behind a container/div while also leaving a small white space under the footer.

I tried using various footers, divs, containers, etc. I am currently using flex and the footer works ok on desktop/tablet. Wondering if I need a media query for mobile..

```css
.footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="footer">
  <p>
    testing to see if can move to bottom
  </p>
</div>
```

Just hoping to have a nice footer with social media icons, that stays on bottom and is responsive on mobile.

Comment: Paragraph elements have a non-zero margin-bottom, by default. You'll need to override that.

Comment: Put padding on the `.footer`. Even 1px will deal with the margin of the paragraph overflowing.

Comment: add a snippet that replicates the issue - current snippet doesn't do that.. we can only guess :)

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you reset the body margin and padding to 0px. In Chrome, for example, the body tag has an 8px margin by default.

[image: 8px margin on body element]

Try to implement a standard reset CSS before implementing your own styles, to prevent browser defaults from changing your layouts and to get a more uniform rendering of your elements.

```css
body {
   background-color: black;
   padding:0px;
   margin: 0px;
}
.footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>
    testing to see if can move to bottom
  </p>
</div>
```

Example of a reset css

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```